# Reading Grails configs from groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I just tried to read a grails config from groovy. The `ConfigSlurper` is easy to use, but since it executes the config, it needs all dependencies in place. In my case, it complains about a missing `log4j` class.
Even when I import this class into my `ConfigSlurper` script, the config itself runs into this problem.

Any Idea how I could make the `log4j` classes accessible to the config?

Update: now that I have a proper keyboard in front of me, I can elaborate on my problem:

I have grails configurations which configure log4j as described in the docs:

```
import org.apache.log4j.*

log4j = { 
  appenders { 
    appender new RollingFileAppender( 
         name: "myAppender", 
         maxFileSize: 1024, 
         file: "/tmp/logs/myApp.log"
    ) 
  } 
}
```

Then I tried to parse them like this:

```
def file = new File(<config location>)
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(file.toURL())
```

and the Slurper threw an exception...

Comment: If you are excecuting any Groovy code (config files or otherwise) which have static references to log4j classes, those log4j classes need to be on the classpath.

Comment: that's what I though but didn't manage to fix. I tried my script within the groovyConsole. It was not a problem to create a new RollingFileAppender in the script, but the ConfigSlurper still complained about it. But I've found a better way to avoid it completely in my config files... found it in the current docs.

Comment: You said "Even when I import this class into my ConfigSlurper script".  Importing isn't enough.  The import won't work if the classes aren't available in the class loader, which normally means available on the classpath.

Comment: Mh. yes, I am aware of the classpath, but I thought that if the surrounding script can access the class... but I've now also found a better solution. Will write it down in just a minute...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found two solutions:

First, the documents show a way how to configure a rollingFileAppender without instantiating one: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/conf.html .

Second, I managed to fix my original problem with a

```
@Grab('log4j:log4j:')
```

in front of my script - not a good solution if you are behind a firewall...

As Jeff already stated, it should also be possible to put the right jar file in the classpath, but I have to say that I often struggle with the cp :-( and when I tried to put the log4j.jar in the .groovy folder, I didn't succeed - but I guess this was because of an inproper groovy installation.